# Cyrillic characters at SSIS Script Task editor

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, encoding, ssis

I wrote some code at SQL Server Integration Services Script Task. And I used some cyrillic characters in that code. They displayed normally during first editing, but after closing Script Task editor, saving SSIS project and opening editor again they become corrupted. When I open editor again they replaced by some rubbish characters. If I don't open editor my code works normally and cyrillic string constants process correctly. I can't find any project or editor properties that allow cyrillic strings in code. Are there any settings like that or I should write my code once and don't open editor again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution:
I opened Tools|Options at Script Task editor menu and checked "Auto-detect UTF-8 encoding without signature" checkbox at Text Editor|General. 
After that I opened project properties at Script Task editor and edited Application|Assembly Information. I changed Neutral Language combobox value to Russian.
Now I can save script and package and cyrillic characters stay safe.